# Should i fridge my expiring meal bars by best used by date?

Tags: storage-method

I got some unopened meal bars, which are best used by today. It's package doesn't say keep in fridge. Is it ok to put it in bedroom with heating? Or keep it in fridge?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The expiration date on dry goods is an indication of quality, rather than safety.  Closet or fridge...in this case probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that doesn't take *damage* from being at fridge temperature will last longer in the fridge, because both biological (spoilage or fermentation) and chemical (well described in the so called arrhenius equation) processes are slowed.

Now could a bar like that take damage (assuming you don't put it in a part of a fridge where it might freeze and suffer textural damage)? There are two likely things that could go wrong with a cereal bar of any kind: Sugars/syrups used could crystallize and degrade texture, and if they are packaged airtight, moisture could condense inside the packaging and soak the outer layers.